# Update a Column with multiple values for different where conditon - Hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate

I need to UPDATE a column in multiple rows(around 2000) with a different value for each WHERE condition. I've List of values for Where condition and another list of values to update the column.

My updates are being done as individual queries like this:

```
UPDATE tablename SET widget='xxx' WHERE widget='zamu';
UPDATE tablename SET widget='yyy' WHERE widget='flabu';
```

Is there any way to do something like this in a single query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE` statement and `IN` operator

```
UPDATE tablename SET widget = CASE WHEN widget='zamu' THEN 'xxx' ELSE 'yyy' END 
WHERE widget IN ('zamu', 'flabu')
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE tablename
SET     widget =  CASE
                        WHEN widget = 'zamu' THEN 'xxx' 
                        ELSE 'yyy'
                    END 
WHERE   widget IN ('zamu', 'flabu')